SAS: Read file names (DOS) with umlauts
GOAL:

read file names including full path using SAS from DOS directories (and their subdirectories) and store them in a database
Umlauts are allowed (ä,ê,ö,ü,ß etc...)
I need the full path in some way (file names only won't do, this is not the problem).

PROBLEM
a) when file or folder names contain umlauts the recorded names do not equal the real file names
b) even the same umlauts (see picture "ü") are sometimes displayed differently.
Files in Explorer and in SAS-Output
This is my last attempt, using SAS to create the dirrectory listing and to import it directly in SAS.
SAS-CODE
filename DIRLIST pipe "dir C:\Z_Backup\LwX\SAS\FilingList\UMLAUTE\ /s";

DATA database ;
     length RawOutput $256 ;
     infile dirlist length=reclen;
     input RawOutput $varying256. reclen ;
RUN;

PROC PRINT; RUN; 

It does not matter, if I create the listing directly in the console and import the rcreated text-file or if I do all in SAS.

What encoding is your SAS session using?  What encoding is your operating system (and/or file server) using?  Try adding ENCODING=ANY to the INFILE statement and see if you can get a consistent string of bytes.  Don't you want the /b option on the DIR command so that it only lists the filename and not the other file attributes?

a) Changing the code line to "infile dirlist encoding=any length=reclen ;" gives the following error message: "Invalid option name ENCODING".
b) I have neither any idea, which encoding systems SAS or my file server are using, nor how to determine that.
c) yes, /b would have been an option. Thanks. However I use the longer output to distinguish between files and folders.

Check the value of ENCODING system option.  PROC OPTIONS OPTION=ENCODING; run;  Apparently you cannot use ENCODING= with the PIPE engine.  You could direct the output of DIR command to a file and read the file with a different encoding.  Or you could just use SAS code like: https://github.com/sasutils/macros/blob/master/dirtree.sas to get the file names and sizes.

Thank you for the valuable comments.
I solved the issue differently:
Instead of reading the directory with SAS, I write a batch-file using SAS. The batch contains the command to change the code page
   C:\>chcp 1252
   Aktive Codepage: 1252.

The text file then contains the correct umlauts and can be imported by SAS without problems.
Here the respective SAS code:
* Create Batch; 
DATA batch; 
    INFORMAT LINE $300.;output;
    Line="chcp 1252 ";output;
    Line="dir &RootStudy. /s >> &DirFilingListDOS.&Akronym._Dateiliste.txt"; output;
    Line="exit"; output; * exit the dos-mode and return to SAS; 
RUN;    

* Export Batch; 
DATA _null_;    SET batch;
    file "&DirFilingListDOS.Create_Dir_&Akronym..bat";
    put Line ;
RUN;

*Start Batch; 
X "&DirFilingListDOS.Create_Dir_&Akronym..bat";

